# XCode build phase: Run AppleScript inside a shell script

Tags: xcode, applescript

I'm having problems getting this to run:

```
BUILD_CONFIRM_SCRIPT="
    try
        tell application \"Xcode\" to display dialog &not;
        activate
\"Do you want to run the translation script? This will take longer to build, but ensure you have the latest translations.\" with title \"Run translation script?\" with icon caution
        return \"Yes\"
        end tell
    on error
        return \"No\"
    end try
"
if [[ $($BUILD_CONFIRM_SCRIPT) == 'No' ]]; then
    exit 0
fi

...
```

What I'm trying to do is this: 
I have this shell script that takes in Localization files and uses this to overwrite all Storyboard/XIB localizations with their respective translations, in order to avoid having to do all of this via code.

The above code is supposed to show an XCode dialog prompting the developer to confirm or deny the execution of the translation script. Executing this takes quite a while and slows down the building process significantly, but luckily it's not necessary to do this every single time. So I wanted to use the above script to abort the execution of the instructions below (see the ...) if the dev doesn't want to or see it necessary.

Running the above script yields an error

```
Syntax error: Expected expression, but found unknown token (-2741)
```

(freely translated, since the original error message is in another language), and after doing research for quite a while now it is time for SO.

For background information, this is the resource I retrieved the original code from: https://cantina.co/adding-interactivity-to-the-xcode-build-process/

Any help is much appreciated! :)

Comment: Have you tried running the script in Script Editor.app?

Comment: Just tried, but apparently I can only run an AppleScript or a JavaScript, not a standard bin/sh. Does this matter? At least it's telling me `„„{““ cannot follow„„)““` in the first line (which is function declaration `trim() {`)

Comment: Sorry, I meant that you can copy the contents of the `BUILD_CONFIRM_SCRIPT`-variable into the Script Editor.app and fix all errors there. It will select the characters that triggered the error.

Comment: Had to strip it to `try
 tell application "Xcode" to display dialog
 
 "Do you want to run the translation script? This will take longer to build, but ensure you have the latest translations."
 activate
 return "Yes"
 
on error
 return "No"
end try` to get it to run. It jumps to XCode, but there's no dialog showing.